# patch FindBoost.cmake for old cmake-3.8.2

Tags: python, boost, cmake

I am forced to use cmake-3.8.2 distributed with poky-2.4.2. When trying to find the boost, I am getting this:

```
CMake Warning at /opt/poky-sdk/2.4.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1536 (message):
  No header defined for python3; skipping header check
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:32 (find_package)
```

This isn't a problem with a newer version of cmake (project finds boost, or I suppose 'python header', just fine with cmake-3.17) Looking around I found [this](https://github.com/boostorg/python/issues/204) which sounds like a solution but unfortunately they do not specify details aside from 'adding the python header as python3 reference in FindBoost.cmake'.

Thought I might be able to cheat and replace the FindBoost.cmake from my toolchain with the FindBoost.cmake from a later version but of course that didn't work (silly me). Currentyl doing a diff between the newer and older modules but but I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking for. Anyone?
.

Comment: So, do you ask us to backport the module `FindBoost.cmake` **for you**? Stack Overflow is not a "code writer" service. Would you want to backport that module **by yourself**, then we could help you. But "by youself" means that your investigations would be much more than "Currenty l doing a diff between the newer and older modules".

Comment: more or less wondering if anyone has run into this and if the is a more simple solution than backporting FindBoost.cmake. but thank you for your helpful comment.

Comment: Usually a boost installation comes with cmake configuration scripts, i.e. you may be able to use the config version of `find_package` to locate boost. Try adding the boost installation dir to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` and `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS ... CONFIG)`

Comment: I also use poky 2.4.2 from day to day. In fact, you are not stuck with cmake 3.8.2 at all. I use cmake 3.18 all the time and everything works just fine.